# Parameter exception in htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to achieve an exception in my htaccess rewrite, so that all requests go to page=[request] except for parameter "lang" so that the rewrites would be like:

www.url.com > www.url.com?page=

www.url.com/pagename > www.url.com?page=pagename

www.url.com?lang=en > www.url.com?page=&lang=en

My htaccess is now:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And the rewrite works nicely on all subpages but not in root/index.

Comment: what do you mean root index? not working on files of root.

Answer (score 0):

Due to presence of `[^/]+` in your pattern it won't match landing page.

You should use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* ?page=$0 [QSA,L]
```

`.*` will match everything including landing page.